# mongodump from remote node - unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-256"

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

Tried taking dump from a remote node and got the following error:

> Failed: can't create session: could not connect to server:
> connection(): auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to
> authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-256": (AuthenticationFailed)
> Authentication failed.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Tried two methods to take dump from the remote node. But got the same error in both the methods.

```
# Method 1
mongodump -h remoteip@port -u xxx -p xxx --db xxx --authenticationDatabase admin

# Method 2
mongodump --uri "mongodb://username:password@remoteip:port/db?authSource=admin"
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Wrong credentials or wrong auth source or user does not exist, use server log to determine which it is.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. I use the same connection string with MongoDB compass, but is failed with mongodump. How have you fix the issue ?

Comment: Maybe using the option --authenticationDatabase admin could resolve your issue.https://github.com/stefanprodan/mgob/issues/104

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue. In my case, the password has special characters. It works with single quote for password:

```
-p 'my_password'
```

Answer (score 21):

For me (trying to use mongodump on a single node DB on the same host), using  `--authenticationDatabase admin` did the trick:

`mongodump -u root --password 'secret' --authenticationDatabase admin -d mongo-dev -o /tmp/dump-2020-11-27.bson`

---

(courtesy of [mongodump from remote node - unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-256"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797865/mongodump-from-remote-node-unable-to-authenticate-using-mechanism-scram-sha-2#comment113349832_62797865))

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer. You need to specify the authSource with `--authenticationDatabase`

Comment: --authenticationDatabase admin

Comment: Thank you for this answer! The error message is very confusing to debug.
Do note that if you created a new db for the data entries while setting up mongo, you will need to use that. `admin` is the default.

Answer (score 6):

1.If you are using an URI for mongodump command,`--authenticationDatabase admin` option is equivalent to `?authSource=admin`

```
mongodump --uri "mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]"
```

sample url:

```
mongodump --uri "mongodb+srv://username1:password1@host1/db1?authSource=admin"
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it using single quotes in the password like this:

```
   --password 'secret'
```

Comment: Surprisingly this worked in a Spring Framework configuration file

Answer (score 0):

Was in the same spot that you are, solved it this way:

```
mongodump --uri "mongodb+srv://username:password@yourmongodbclustersourceurl" --archive \
mongorestore --uri "mongodb+srv://username:password@yourmongodbclusterdestinationurl" --archive \
--nsExclude "admin.system.*"
```

Needless to mention, you just need to change your username, password and the url in this formula and voila. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**I had that problem and solved it by removing the special characters**. For example, in my case I had a password abc@123. The connection string would be

```
mongodb://myuser:abc@123@127.0.0.0:27017/mydb?authSource=admin
```

as we can see a problem is generated because the "@" is a special character to separate the elements of the connection string , and I had to replace it with "%40", so my password was left as "abc%40123". And depending on the console that I used (powershell, command prompt, git bash, etc.) it generated the backup with an error or with a correct response. By removing the "@" everything worked correctly.

Possibly there is some way to configure this encryption, but in my case I preferred to change the password. I hope it will be useful to someone, greetings.